# Create a sails.js hooks with models

Tags: sails.js

I want to create a sails.js hook which has it own model.
How can I inject this model into the current app ?

I've found this : https://github.com/leeroybrun/sails-hook-hookloader, but I don't understand how it work.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

I've found an easy way to do it !

I've just created symlinks of all the hook models files to the main app "api/models" folder !

My initialize function look like that :

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

module.exports = function ToInitialize(sails) {

    return function initialize(cb) {

       // the path of the Hook model
       var modelFile = path.join(__dirname, '../models/Model.js');
       // the destination path
       var modelFileDest = path.join(sails.config.appPath, 'api/models/Model.js');

       if (!fs.existsSync(modelFileDest)) {
          // create a symlink to the api/models folder 
          fs.symlink(modelFile, modelFileDest, 'file', cb);
       } else {
          return cb();
       }

    }; 
};
```

Comment: Good workaround but I think it's better to do like the project you pointing on your question. You can try to use it and call injectModel on the initialize method (with correct dir param)

Comment: Here is how to use it :) https://github.com/leeroybrun/sails-hook-hookloader/issues/1

Comment: Wow thanks this rocks ! That's just what I needed. 
Thanks for your example in your git repo, it just works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks !! I didn't have time to test it so if you have problem with it don't hesitate !! :D